# Modifying the data in a database in one mobile and retrieving the modified data in other mobile

Tags: android, database, mobile

i created 3 activities in which one has the queries in it as the one below

```
        spsrchcity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int itemcity, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selsrchcty=spsrchcity.getSelectedItem().toString();


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    spsrcharea.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int itemarea, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selsrcharea=spsrcharea.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    spsrchhstlfr.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int itemhstlfr, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selsrchfr=spsrchhstlfr.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    spsrchhstltyp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int itemtype, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selsrchtyp=spsrchhstltyp.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


    btnsrchrm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Cursor c;
            //sdb=openOrCreateDatabase("Hostels", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            //c=sdb.rawQuery("select Hostel Name, City, Area, Type, For, Rating , Phone No:  from Hostels where City ='"+selcty+"' and Area='"+selarea+"' and For='"+selfr+"' and Type='"+seltyp+"' "  ,null);

            Intent isrch=new Intent(SearchRoom.this,SearchResult.class);

            Bundle bndlsrch=new Bundle();

            bndlsrch.putString("keycity", selsrchcty);
            bndlsrch.putString("keyarea", selsrcharea);
            bndlsrch.putString("keyfor", selsrchfr);
            bndlsrch.putString("keytype", selsrchtyp);
            isrch.putExtras(bndlsrch);
            startActivity(isrch);

        }
    });
```

and  the other is for showing the result for the one in the query above

```
    srchrslt=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1SrchResult);
    dbsrch=openOrCreateDatabase("Hostels", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    String scty=getIntent().getStringExtra("keycity");
    String sarea=getIntent().getStringExtra("keyarea");
    String sfor=getIntent().getStringExtra("keyfor");
    String styp=getIntent().getStringExtra("keytype");

    dbsrch=openOrCreateDatabase("Hostels", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    crsrsrch=dbsrch.rawQuery("select Hostel Name ,  City, Area, Type, For, Rating , Phone No:  from Hostels where City ='"+scty+"' and Area='"+sarea+"' and For='"+sfor+"' and Type='"+styp+"' and Flag='1' "  ,null);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adsrch=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
    srchrslt.setAdapter(adsrch);


    while (crsrsrch.moveToNext()) {

    String HostelName=crsrsrch.getString(0);
    String City=crsrsrch.getString(1);
    String Area=crsrsrch.getString(2);
    String HostelType=crsrsrch.getString(3);
    String HostelFor=crsrsrch.getString(4);
    String Rating=crsrsrch.getString(5);
    String PhoneNum=crsrsrch.getString(6);

    adsrch.add("Hostel Name:"+HostelName+"\nCity:"+City+"\nArea:"+Area+"\nHostel Type:"+HostelType+"\nHostel For:"+HostelFor+"\nRating for the Hostel:"+Rating+"\nPhone Number:"+PhoneNum+"\n\n");

    }

    crsrsrch.close();
    dbsrch.close();
  }
```

and the other one for adding the values into the database as follows:

```
     name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1addname);

    phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1addphonenum);

    addhostel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1addHostel);

    addhostelname=name.getText().toString();
    addhostelphone=phone.getText().toString();

    spaddcity=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1addCity);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaddcity=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,addcity);
    spaddcity.setAdapter(adaddcity);

    spaddarea=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2addArea);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaddarea=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,addarea);
    spaddarea.setAdapter(adaddcity);

    spaddhostelfor=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3addHostelFor);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaddhostelfor=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,addhostelfor);
    spaddhostelfor.setAdapter(adaddhostelfor);


    spaddhosteltype=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4addHostelType);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaddhosteltype=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,addhosteltype);
    spaddhosteltype.setAdapter(adaddhosteltype);


    spaddcity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            seladdcty=spaddcity.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    spaddarea.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            seladdarea=spaddarea.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    spaddhostelfor.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            seladdhostelfor=spaddhostelfor.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    });

    spaddhosteltype.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            seladdhosteltype=spaddhosteltype.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


    addhostel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            dbadd=openOrCreateDatabase("Hostels", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            dbadd.execSQL("insert into Hostels values('"+addhostelname+"','"+seladdcty+"','"+seladdarea+"','"+seladdhostelfor+"','"+seladdhosteltype+"','0','"+addhostelphone+"','0');");

        }
    });
```

now my question is if i have it installed in 2 mobiles and if on one mobile i added some data how to retrieve that data on the other mobile?

please help me out..

thanks in advance..

Sai Srinivas

Comment: ur database file is accessible with in ur application because  database permission you used `mode_private` this is means database will store in application data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..can u suggest me the permission i should use??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this, one need to have a server so that every change to the database goes to the server and then the change reflects to the phones having the application through updates...